# Title based Slug for URLs in django without app label

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I got products app with ListView and DetailView. I need to implement slug with title of products on detail page with no app label in url. Such as in detail page it should say 'mysite.com/complete-product-title' instead of 'mysite.com/products/complete-product-title'. This detail page can help me to great deal for SEO.

Following is the code:

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    sku = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)
    default = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='default_category', null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs={"slug": self.slug}
        return reverse('product_detail', kwargs=kwargs)
```

Views.py:

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        query = super(ProductListView, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        return query

class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    slug_field = 'slug'
```

Project urls.py:

```
url(r'^products/', include('products.urls')),
```

App urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product_detail'),
```

I have implemented elasticsearch with haystack and for it I have to add haystack urls in project root urls.py like     `url(r'^$', include('haystack.urls'), name='search'),`

My complete models.py for products app are

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    sku = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=False)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)
    default = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='default_category', null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_detail', kwargs={"slug":self.slug})

    def get_image_url(self):
        img = self.productimage_set.first()
        if img:
            return img.image.url
        return img

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    #slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

def image_upload_to(instance, filename):
    title = instance.product.title
    slug = slugify(title)
    basename, file_extension = filename.split('.')
    new_filename = '%s-%s.%s'%(basename, instance.id, file_extension)
    return 'products/%s/%s' %(slug, new_filename)
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.product.title
```

When I try to add `slug=models.SlugField(unique=True)` I get error message like `column slug is not unique`.

Now I can't remove `products/` from `url(r'^products/', include('products.urls')),` because then it will make haystack urls and product app urls both default. Ultimate goal here is to just implement haystack urls as default but not showing `'mysite.com/products/product-title-as-slug'` instead `'mysite.com/product-title-as-slug'`.

Please assist how can I achieve this goal.

Comment: Do you mean you just want your product urls at the root of the site like `url(r'^', include('products.urls')),`?

Comment: I understand that instead of adding urls in app based urls.py I can directly add it in project based urls.py so then it will be "mysite.com/complete-product-title' instead of 'mysite.com/products/complete-product-title'. But how to implement it in generic based detail view. Simply how to add title as slug in url for product_detail page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this immediately by changing:

```
url(r'^products/', include('products.urls')),
```

to

```
url(r'^', include('products.urls')),
```

This is all you would need to do if your site is not yet live. Otherwise you should also write in a 301 redirect from your old URLs (mysite.com/products/complete-product-title) to your new ones at the same time.

Comment: I see but I thought it definitely needs a reference for new urls.py file under some app. I was stupid coz 'products/' part has nothing to do with regex. Now tell me how to implement title as slug for urls. Because what I've added above is not working for me its popping up error. It is simple enough as before I just had to add a slug field in model and add a function as get_absolute_url. At end of it I would return slug as self.slug. But its not working for me please assist.

Comment: @ShaziaNusrat you should probably add those as two separate questions - one is how to make your slug field unique and the other is how to address this with respect to haystack.

Comment: I am trying to redirect search query on 'search/' for haystack and use 'products/' as my default urls. If I failed I will definitely post two separate questions.